# Implementing Goldbach's conjecture in Haskell, lots of restrictions

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, primes, goldbach-conjecture

The point of this assignment is to understand list comprehensions.

Implementing Goldbach's conjecture for some natural number (otherwise the behavior does not matter) using several pre-defined functions and under the following restrictions:

- no auxiliary functions
- no use of *where* or *let*
- only one defining equation on the left-hand side and the right-hand side *must* be a list comprehension
- the order of the pairs in the resulting list is irrelevant
- using functions from Prelude is allowed

```
-- This part is the "library" 

dm :: Int -> [ Int ] -> [ Int ]
dm x xs = [ y | y <- xs , y `mod ` x /= 0]

da :: [ Int ] -> [ Int ]
da ( x : xs ) = x : da ( dm x xs )

primes :: [ Int ]
primes = da [2 ..]

-- Here is my code
goldbach :: Int -> [(Int,Int)]

-- This is my attempt 1
goldbach n = [(a, b) | n = a + b, a <- primes, b <- primes, a < n, b < n]

-- This is my attempt 2
goldbach n = [(a, b) | n = a + b, a <- takeWhile (<n) primes, b <- takeWhile (<n) primes]
```

Expected result: a list of all pairs summing up to the specified integer. But GHC complains that in the comprehension, n is not known. My gut tells me I need some Prelude function(s) to achieve what I need, but which one?

---

**Update**

```
parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let n = 5' instead of 'n = 5'
```

Comment: Post the error you get please. You don't even mention x, strange that it would say it's not known

Comment: @FabianSchneider that would require `a + b` to be a list.  `let n = a+b` there probably matches the intention.

Comment: @luqui true; I think that this is actually what he meant: `goldbach n = [(a, b) | a <- takeWhile (<n) primes, b <- takeWhile (<n) primes, n == a + b]` ensuring that n is actually a + b in the tuple...

Comment: You can't use `a` before it's defined by `a <- ...`. Ditto for `b`. Move `n == a+b` at the end.

Comment: `goldbach n = (n, [(a, b) | a <- da [2..n], b <- da [2..n], a+b==n] )`.

Comment: @mushishi : did the answer solve your problem? if so please accept it; if not, please provide some more details ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding the weird error you are talking about, I think that the problem you actually have is the following:

As mentioned by @chi and me, you can't use a and b in your final comprehension before you define a and b.
so you have to move it to the and.

Also: equality of integers is checked with `(==)` not `(=)` in haskell.
So you also need to change that.

This would be the complete code for your final approach:

`goldbach n = [(a, b) | a <- takeWhile (<n) primes, b <- takeWhile (<n) primes, n == a + b]`

A small test yields:

```
*Main> goldbach 5
[(2,3),(3,2)]
```

**Update**

If you want to achieve what you wrote in your comment, you can just add another condition to your comprehension

```
n `mod` 2 == 0
```

or even better: Define your funtion with a guard like this:

```
goldbach n
  | n `mod` 2 == 0 = [(a, b) | a <- takeWhile (<n) primes, b <- takeWhile (<n) primes, n == a + b]
  | otherwise = []
```

However, if I am not mistaken this has nothing to do with the actual Godbach conjecture.

Comment: *Foo> goldbach 23  []

Comment: According to wikipedia the goldbach conjecture states `Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.` which implies that it is only defined for even numbers; which implies that it does not hold for 23

Comment: Still ```goldbach 25``` yields ```[(2,23),(23,2)]``` even though it should be [] for any positive odd integer. And thanks for pointing out the importance of the order of conditions in the comprehension!

Comment: @mushishi: no, this works as an implication, not as an equivalence. Any even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as a sum of two primes, that does not say anything about the odd numbers. It can happen that it is impossible, as well as it can happen that it is possible.